# Is it possbile to restrict who can connect to Postgres using Active Directory Groups

Tags: active-directory, postgresql

I am setting up a postgres server that will accept connections that have been authenticated using the SSPI method. These accounts will then be mapped to a single postgres role using the pg_ident.conf file. Is there a way to differentiate between users based on group or OU in the mapping file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible as-is; postgres ignores all group information from the SSPI token. However, it should be possible to modify [auth.c](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/libpq/auth.c) to retrieve TokenPrimaryGroup instead of [TokenUser](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/libpq/auth.c#l1443). Then you could use the identity mapping from AD group names to roles (or explicitly map all relevant AD groups to their respective roles).

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I'll ask on their dev list if that is a decent feature for them to add as well.